# 'Failed to read descriptor from node connection:' error in C# VS Code 2019 Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver

When I run a program (code is below) in C#-Selenium-Visual Studio Code 2019, I get a 'Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning.' The program launches the browser, I get an "Windows Defender Antivirus wants to reset your settings" pop-up for a few seconds, 'Failed to read...' message comes up in a console, and the program ends.
Based on my online research, this issue is triggered by Chrome attempting to read properties of USB devices that are currently suspended.

[image: Failed to read descriptor from node connection - console screenshot]

I tried the following to troubleshoot:

1. Checked browser version - up-to-date - and if Windows Updates are needed - none are.
2. Other users here at Stack had similar issues. For someone, unplugging USBs worked. I unplugged all USB devices from my PC and re-ran the program but no luck.
3. I put 'executable_path=r' in front of "https:/..." but that doesn't work either.
4. I went to chrome://flags to see if I can enable 'Enable new USB backend option' but there isn't this option or any option with USB.

   `class EntryPoint
   {
   static void Main()
   {

   IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://testing.todorvachev.com/");
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
   driver.Quit();
   }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

...implies that the ChromeDriver raised an error while in trying to initiate/spawn a new Browsing Context i.e. google-chrome session.

[How does chrome driver interact with Chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).